# Не запускается видео на странице

Tags: html, видео

Появляются иконки видео (звук, дорожка воспроизведения, кнопка увеличения экрана и т.д.), фото, которое я указал в атрибуте poster. А само видео не запускается. Что делать?

```
  <html>
     <head>
      <title>Добавление видео на страницу</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <video src="C://Пользователи/1/Загрузки/snake.mp4" controls loop autoplay poster="images/c++.jpg">
       <p>Быстрый кодинг игры Змейка</p>
      </video>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: В другом браузере тоже не запускается?

Comment: А попробуйте не через атрибут src, а через дочерний тег <source>

Comment: Из за политики безопасности доступ напрямую к файловой системе возможен только если mp4 файл будет в той же папке или её подпапках что и html. И ссылку нужно писать относительную.

Comment: "@coder675 не помогло

Comment: Всем спасибо! Всё работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай файл html с таким содержанием.

```
 <html>
     <head>
      <title>Добавление видео на страницу</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <video src="snake.mp4" controls loop autoplay poster="images/c++.jpg">
       <p>Быстрый кодинг игры Змейка</p>
      </video>
     </body>
    </html>
```

В ту же папку положи файл с видео. `snake.mp4`
У меня все работает.

Comment: Но есть одна проблема. Почему-то не работает autoplay. Видео не запускается само.

Comment: В хроме с 53 версии аутоплей не работает если видео не указано как без звука.   Вот так работает.  <video autoplay controls muted><source src="snake.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>

Comment: Спасибо. Ещё вопрос: Видео файл нужно располагать в той же папке или подпапке, что и файл html, только при использовании тега video? Или нужно поступать также и при добавлении видео любыми другими способами, например flash контента с помощью сценариев JS?